# How to manage large data set in redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When storing large something like 100000 records. It is for data plotting in highcharts. When setting API response to redux store browser to become hang

Comment: add some code as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Large amount of data can cause browser to hang, but not so often, i'll suggest you check for infinite loop in your codes, thats is the first source of browser hanging especially in `react/redux` applications, as `hooks` when mismanaged a little cause this problem,
2. But if the source of problem is large amount of data, then query in chunks, until you have all the data required in your application store, plus for optimization. dont query any data you dont need for the moment,